# Referencing CSS within CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to define a CSS class as being equal to another? For example if I had a class:

```
.myClass{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

is there a way to define a second class as having the same style as myClass without just copying and pasting?

EDIT:

Sorry, let me be a bit more clear. Is it possible to do this after declaring the first class, possibly even in another stylesheet?

Comment: I edited my answer, to include a link to SASS,  which is what you might be looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
.myClass,
.mySecondClass,
.myThirdClass {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your edit: What you might be looking for, if this is something you really want to do is to look into [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) which basically is like css but with variables and stuffs. But vanilla CSS doesn't have any native support for what you want.

Comment: Wow SASS looks awesome, Why have I never heard of it before!?

Comment: I know! I haven't tried it myself either actually. CSS usually becomes a mess when a project becomes big, and I think that maybe (maybe) SASS or LESS might be the solution to that mess. Rails3.1 uses SASS as default language instead of css now actually. Which is pretty awesome. So expect to hear more about SASS and related technologies in the future!

Answer (score 2):

Not with plain CSS. You can do this using a technology called SASS (http://sass-lang.com/), by using the `@extend` function.

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend

I think LESS also has this ability, but I've not verified it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking about creating some sort of variables for your css? If that's the case, you should look into [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Both of which allow for style variables such as:

```
/* sass/less css */
@color: #4D926F;

#header { color: @color; }
h2 { color: @color; }

/* rendered css */
#header { color: #4D926F; }
h2 { color: #4D926F; }
```

LESS also has [nested rules](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules) so if you have overlapping rules, you don't constantly have to write them over and over.

```
/* rendered css */
#header { color: black; }
#header .navigation {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#header .logo { 
  width: 300px; 
}
#header .logo:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* less css */
#header        { color: black;
  .navigation  { font-size: 12px }
  .logo        { width: 300px;
    &:hover    { text-decoration: none }
  }
}
```

Hope this gives you more of a starting point :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.myClass, .myOtherClass{
    background-color: blue;
}
```